# How to find out promoted tweets from twitter?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I'm currently doing a project on Twitter data, and I'd like to identify whether the tweets are promoted or not.
I mean, you guys can see promoted tweets from your homepage all the time, but I collect some of them and couldn't find any clear label called promoted from the source field.
Does anyone have any idea how to identify these?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you collect them?

Comment: @Efferalgan Via Tweepy, it's an API for collecting data from Twitter, both REST api and Streaming api.

Comment: I saw the `Tweepy` tag, yes. My question was, are you getting them via REST or Streaming, and then are you fetching a timeline (`user_timeline`), a single tweet via `get_status`, are you making a `search`…

Comment: No, I mean, because the search operation via REST api will not return any information about promoted tweets, so I didn't use it. I'm currently collecting promoted tweets from my homepage manually... It's pretty stupid, but I couldn't find a better way so far...

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the regular API, Twitter doesn't included promoted Tweets.  This is because they cannot guarantee to advertisers how the tweet will display.

If you have an advertiser account, you can find some information out about promoted tweets using [`GET accounts/:account_id/promoted_tweets`](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/reference/get/accounts/%3Aaccount_id/promoted_tweets) - but this probably isn't what you wanted.